# .net windows form application setup shortcut icon at custom location

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, installation, setup-deployment

I have to put .net windows form application setup shortcut icon at custom locations like quick launch menu or some in some other directory while installation. Currently i have only option to put it on Desktop and in Start Menu(Start Menu -> All Programs -> "Shortcut")
How can i do it? I tried to edit custom action but didn't find any way to make it work.

Comment: Have you looked at WiX (Windows Installer XML)?

Comment: If your install system can run sort of `installation code` (or script), then use it, to make that extra you need.

Comment: my project has been built in VS 2008 and and i am using Setup Wizard in Setup and Deployment.

Comment: Check this solution http://superuser.com/questions/392061/how-to-make-a-shortcut-from-cmd

Comment: Avoid splattering your icon *every where*, users really hate that.  Especially QuickLaunch, that's prime real estate that's not yours to mess with.  Ask at superuser.com if you need to find the registry and folder locations.  Be specific.